# how to get jupyter %%bash to display output in real time

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

In a Jupyter notebook the following code prints the numbers one by one in real time as the code loops:

```
!for i in `seq 1 5`; do echo $i; sleep 1 ; done
```

However, I see the entire output appear only at the end of the loop with the following:

```
%%bash
for i in `seq 1 5`; do echo $i; sleep 1 ; done
```

Is there a way to get the `%%bash` method to display output in real time?

Answer (score 4):

IPython's [cell magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-bash) for bash is itself a shortcut for `%%script bash` and will not output to display until a cell has exited. You can get around this however to view a cell's output in real time by swapping the bash magic with either `%%shell`, `%%system` or the latter's shortcut `%%!`:

```
%%shell
for i in `seq 1 5`; do echo $i; sleep 1 ; done
```