# Running Linux Commands in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, bash, elasticsearch, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have a google colab file that I want to run in Visual Studio Code. Normal cells are running ok but I have the following cell:

```
# 1. Downloads, extracts, and sets the permissions for the Elasticsearch installation image:
%%bash

wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.9.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz -q
tar -xzf elasticsearch-7.9.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
chown -R daemon:daemon elasticsearch-7.9.2
```

The problem is that I am getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` on the `wget`

I have tried multiple solutions from stackoverflow

1. Use the generic `%%bash` I use in Google Colab too.
2. Use `%%shell`
3. Use the longer version of 1, `%%script bash`
4. Use `%%script` bash
5. Use the shortcut `%%!`

I used source like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71385453/how-to-get-jupyter-bash-to-display-output-in-real-time), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54604995/how-to-run-a-script-shell-in-google-colab). [This](https://haystack.deepset.ai/tutorials/03_scalable_qa_system) is the tutorial I used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the solution by myself

```
# 1. Downloads, extracts, and sets the permissions for the Elasticsearch installation image:
%%!

!wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.9.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz -q
!tar -xzf elasticsearch-7.9.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
!chown -R daemon:daemon elasticsearch-7.9.2
```

This is the correct syntax

Comment: Nice one, I'll delete my solution because it looks like I was way off  (-2 points!!)

Comment: No worries pal. Helping people is ok even when you are off. your time is appreciated.